# Enviar parametros para comando SQL como variable parametrizada

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

Necesito enviar los parametros que usaré en un comando sql, sé que se puede hacer con `Dim paramater As New SqlParameter("@fptemp", serializedTemplate)` pero ahora viene el problema cuando uso una función parametrizable para hacer la ejecución del comando, en esta función uso lo siguiente:

```vb
Public Function StrInsert_and_Update_With_Parameters(ByVal Query As String, ByVal Parameters As SqlParameter)
Dim vl_S_processUpdate As String

Try
            'Iniciamos la conexión a la BD
            Dim objConexBD As New SqlConnection(ConectionString)

            'Abrimos conexión
            objConexBD.Open()
            'Creamos el comando a ejecutar y seleccionamos tipo de comando
            Dim objcmd As New SqlCommand(Query, objConexBD)
            objcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            'Montamos los parametros el comando
            objcmd.Parameters.Add(Parameters)
            'Ejecutamos el CMD
            objcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            'Cerramos conexiones
            objConexBD.Close()

            vl_S_processUpdate = "Exito"

        Catch ex As Exception

            vl_S_processUpdate = "Error"
        End Try
        Return vl_S_processUpdate

    End Function
```

Pero desde mi función donde arme el comando no sé como enviarlo, ahí tengo

```vb
 Dim sql As New StringBuilder

 sql.AppendLine("INSERT PERSONA (" & _
                "P_Documento, " & _
                "P_Nombre, " & _
                "P_Apellido, " & _
                "P_Usuario_Creacion, " & _
                "P_FechaCreacion, " & _
                "P_Usuario_Actualizacion, " & _
                "P_FechaActualizacion" & _
                ")")
sql.AppendLine("VALUES (")
        sql.AppendLine("@Documento, ")
        sql.AppendLine("@Nombre, ")
        sql.AppendLine("@Apellido, ")
        sql.AppendLine("'" & vp_Obj.UsuarioCreacion & "', ")
        sql.AppendLine("'" & vp_Obj.FechaCreacion & "', ")
        sql.AppendLine("'" & vp_Obj.UsuarioActualizacion & "', ")
        sql.AppendLine("'" & vp_Obj.FechaActualizacion & "' ) ")

Dim paramater As New SqlParameter("@Documento", DocumentPerson) <-- ESTO ES LO QUE NO SÉ CÓMO SE PUEDE ARMAR PARA ENVIARLO COMO PARÁMETRO

Query = sql.ToString

Result = conex.StrInsert_and_Update_With_Parameters(Query, paramater)
```

Como podria hacer eso?, es decir, armar todo un archivo de tipo `SqlParameter` para poderlo enviar como parámetro y utilizarlo al otro lado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes acumular tus parámetros en una lista y pasar la lista a `StrInsert_and_Update_With_Parameters`:

```vb
Dim parametros As List(Of SqlParameter) = New List(Of SqlParameter)
parametros.Add(New SqlParameter("@Documento", DocumentPerson))
' agregar otros parámetros aquí

Query = sql.ToString

Result = conex.StrInsert_and_Update_With_Parameters(Query, parametros)
```

Tendrías que modificar la declaración del método `StrInsert_and_Update_With_Parameters` para aceptar una lista de parámetros, por ejemplo:

```vb
Public Function StrInsert_and_Update_With_Parameters(Query As String, parametros As IEnumerable(Of SqlParameter)) As String
```

Y dentro del método, en vez de:

```vb
objcmd.Parameters.Add(Parameters)
```

... puedes hacer:

```vb
objcmd.Parameters.AddRange(parametros.ToArray())
```

Comment: Una duda, que hace eso de `As IEnumerable(Of SqlParameter)) As String` ?, estoy probando tu código a ver...

Comment: Permite que el que llame el método le pueda pasar una lista de `SqlParameter`. También pudiera haber sido definido como `As List(Of SqlParameter)` o un con un array: `parametros As SqlParameter()`. Pero el uso del interface `IEnumerable` es una buena práctica porque es mas amplio y acepta objetos de tipo `List` o arrays sin problemas.

Comment: @FabianMontoya sobre tu pregunta de `IEnumerable(Of SqlParameter)`, te recomiendo [Covarianza y contravarianza en genéricos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx), cabe indicarte que la clase [`SqlParameterCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection(v=vs.110).aspx) hereda de [`DbParameterCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.common.dbparametercollection(v=vs.110).aspx), la cual tiene firmada con la interfaz `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Si correcto, disculpa, ya lo solucione, tu idea funcionó correctamente